# Trying to add an extra element to an XSD file

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd

I have an XSD file that contains the following...

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" id="OTA2003A" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" version="1.000" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">

  <xs:element name="OTA_VehAvailRateRQ">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>The root tag of OTA_VehAvailRateRQ contains standard payload attributes found in all OTA payload documents. Because the results of the search message could be quite numerous, the request also has an attribute, MaxResponses, indicating the number of replies requested.  The attribute  ReqRespVersion is a positive integer value that indicates the version number requested for the response message.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="POS" type="POS_Type">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Point of Sale Identification.  Identification number of the vendor that has made the vehicle availability request and agency number assigned by IATA, ARC, ESRP or TID.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="VehAvailRQCore" type="VehicleAvailRQCoreType">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Identifies the common, or core, information associated with the request for availability of a rental vehicle.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="VehAvailRQInfo" type="VehicleAvailRQAdditionalInfoType">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Identifies the supplemental information associated with the request for availability of a rental vehicle.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="OTA_PayloadStdAttributes"/>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="ReqRespVersion"/>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="MaxResponsesGroup"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I am then referencing this in a WSDL file. When I run the WSDL file through something like SoapUI I get the following output as a soap request...

```
<soap:Body>
    <OTA_VehAvailRateRQ EchoToken="XXX1234" Version="1.0" ReqRespVersion="medium" MaxResponses="16" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">      
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
</soap:Body>
```

...So far, so good. Now I need to add an element to the XSD file so that it will produce the following output...

```
<soap:Body>
    <ns:Request xmlns:ns="http://someurl">
        <OTA_VehAvailRateRQ EchoToken="XXX1234" Version="1.0" ReqRespVersion="medium" MaxResponses="16" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
    </ns:Request>
</soap:Body>
```

...Note the extra tag in there. This is where I am struggling. Does anyone know how I should modify the original XSD to produce the extra tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would create a Request tag outside the OTA_VehAvailRateRQ

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=...>

<xs:element name="Request">
<xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="OTA_VehAvailRateRQ">
    ...
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I try that the output appears as...<soapenv:Body>
      <ns:OTA_VehAvailRateRQ/>
   </soapenv:Body>

Comment: Really? That shouldn't be the case.  It should add a 'Request' tag around it.

Comment: Actually, that did work, I just did not update the WSDL file to point at the request element instead of the OTA_VehAvailRateRQ element. Thanks.